# Cosmos SDK remote connection refused

Tags: blockchain

I am new to Cosmos SDK and I just forked the [official Cosmos SDK nameservice tutorial](https://tutorials.cosmos.network/). It works well on my local machine so I just deployed it to cloud server and I want to access it thru nscli from my local machine.

First I configured nscli to set the node to remote server address on my local machine
`nscli config node tcp://{{my remote server ip here}}:26657`

Then I tried to run the following query
`nscli query account $(nscli keys show jack -a)`

Finally I got some error like `ERROR: ABCIQuery: Post failed: Post "{{my remote server ip}}:26657": dial tcp : connect: connection refused`

I am curios since I don't think there is any network related problem in my case. Did I mis-configured something?

Thank you very much!

Best,
Min

Answer (score 2):

My config file is configured to listen on 127.0.0.1:26657, which should be set to 0.0.0.0:26657 instead. So the connection succeeded if I start the daemon node like `tendermint node --rpc.laddr=tcp://0.0.0.0:26657`